# python opencv cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT get wrong numbers

Tags: python, opencv

```
import os
import cv2
path='/home/nlpr4/video-data/UCF-101/GolfSwing/v_GolfSwing_g24_c06.avi'
cap=cv2.VideoCapture(path)
video_length=int(cap.get(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT))

success=True
count=0
while success:
    success,image=cap.read()
    if success==False:
        break
    count=count+1

print video_length,count
```

output:

```
149 
146
```

why the two numbers different?
what's wrong?

Comment: Not sure, but I think read FRAME COUNT would require reading total number of frames from file metadata, but count variable needs actual decoding of frame. if decoding of 147th frame failed, this would cause the issue.

Comment: 2 years has passed. And there is no more new answers. Is it possible to accept my answer?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The get() for `CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT` is never supposed to be accurate! If you check the opencv source code. You can find this:

```
int64_t CvCapture_FFMPEG::get_total_frames() const
{
    int64_t nbf = ic->streams[video_stream]->nb_frames;

    if (nbf == 0)
    {
        nbf = (int64_t)floor(get_duration_sec() * get_fps() + 0.5);
    }
    return nbf;
}
```

This means it will first look into the stream header for `nb_frames`, which you can check with ffprobe. If there is no such field, then there is no better way to get frame number than directly decoding the video. The opencv did a rough estimation by `get_duration_sec() * get_fps() + 0.5` which surely not mean for accuracy.

Thus, to obtain the correct frame number you have to decode and read through the entire stream, or you have to ask the video generator to generate correct stream header with `nb_frames` field.

Comment: This answer is incorrect and misleading. There is nothing wrong with OpenCV's calculation here; it takes the expected number of frames and rounds it to the nearest integer. There is nothing inaccurate about this rounding because the duration of a video is always a multiple of 1/FPS. The answer by @ilke444 is the true answer.

Comment: Even though the answer is not 100% precise, sharing the implementation details makes it easy to understand what is going on under the hood - and makes it obvious where potential errors can occur (nb_frames not present, inaccurate fps, rounding errors ...)

Answer (score 9):

[`CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT`](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d8/dfe/classcv_1_1VideoCapture.html#aeb1644641842e6b104f244f049648f94) gives the property of 'number of frames', that comes from the video header. The other number is basically "How many frames can I read from this video file?".

If the video contains frames that cannot be read/decoded (e.g., due to being corrupted), OpenCV skips those frames (after trying to read them) and gives you the next valid frame. So the difference between your two numbers is the number of frames that couldn't be read.

Also, if your video header is corrupted and/or cannot be parsed by the underlying codecs that OpenCV uses, then those numbers can be different too.

Comment: apparently there is no CV_ in front it is just CAP_

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import numpy as np
import cv2

video = "../videos/sample.avi"

video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(video)
video_length = int(video_capture.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT))

count = 0
while(True):
        # Capture frame-by-frame
        ret, frame = video_capture.read()
        if not ret:
            break

        count += 1

print video_length, count
# When everything done, release the capture
video_capture.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

On my machine it gives me:

```
$ ./openstack_video_frames.py 
1232 1232
```

Comment: i had the same question, it gives the correct video_length for some videos, but fails for others, All the videos are the same format, same compression, there can be a difference of 0, 1, 2, 3, up to 3 after i tested 20 videos. I dont know if that is a bug of opencv....