# python cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT get wrong result, and also the cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS get wrong fps

Tags: python, opencv

I want to use `cv2` to extract frames from a `.mkv` video file. The following is my code. I get wrong results for fps and frame count. I tried opencv versions 4.7.xx and 4.8.xx but still get the same problem. How shall I deal with this? The actual fps of my video file is 30 and the total frame count is around 15000.

```
import time
import cv2

video_file_name = 'my_video_0.mkv'
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(video_file_name)
fps = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS) # 1000.0
frame_count = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT)) # -9223372036854775808
```

Thank you all for helping me !!!

Comment: you may check your video header to see if it contains a video frame count attribute.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31472155/python-opencv-cv2-cv-cv-cap-prop-frame-count-get-wrong-numbers